# Replace far left breadcrumbs with ellipsis or dropdown at mobile breakpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a bootstrap web page where we want to use breadcrumbs for users to track where they are at. I have the breadcrumb html and css where I want it, but I need to make them responsive for mobile devices. I would like to have it automatically show maybe the last 2 or 3 breadcrumbs, depending on the length of them so they fit in mobile devices, then replace the remaining left breadcrumbs with either an ellipsis that users can click on to go back further or a dropdown menu for them to click and select the hidden breadcrumbs.

I am not skilled with javascript/jQuery (I am trying to learn this now). Is there a way to easily do this using js/jQuery or possibly even with pure css?

Below is my HTML and CSS as well as jsfiddle link.

https://jsfiddle.net/htrrbmu5/

HTML:

```
<div class="cont_principal">
    <div class="cont_breadcrumbs">
        <div class="cont_breadcrumbs" id="navBread">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Dr Know</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABC Electric</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">IT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ANDY_ASUS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Scan</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2017/12/02 14:03:02</a></li>
            </ul>                                       
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cont_principal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
    margin-left: -35px;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d4e4ef', endColorstr='#86aecc',GradientType=0 );

} 

.cont_breadcrumbs {
  width: auto;
}

.cont_breadcrumbs {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.cont_breadcrumbs > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);  
  background-color: #06bd0a;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  margin-left: 5px;
  list-style: none;

}

.cont_breadcrumbs > ul > li:hover {
 background-color: #3e496a;
}

.cont_breadcrumbs > ul > li  > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: skewX(15deg);
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.cont_breadcrumbs > ul > li:last-child {
  background-color: #252d44;
}

.cont_breadcrumbs > ul > li:last-child > a {
  color: #fff; 

}
```

Comment: Did you OK with .cont_breadcrumbs > ul { display: flex; } ?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd just hide the breadcrumbs on mobile, I'm not convinced they're that useful to be honest.

Anyway, if you want to go the dropdown method I wouldn't display any of the breadcrumbs, just take advantage of Bootstrap's hidden responsive utilities. Hide the breadcrumbs on xl and sm, and hide the dropdown on md, lg and xl.

Below is a partially fleshed out solution using jQuery for the select bits and the hidden utilities.

HTML

```
<div class="cont_principal">
  <div class="cont_breadcrumbs">
    <div class="cont_breadcrumbs" id="navBread">
      <ul class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <li><a href="#">Dr Know</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABC Electric</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">IT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ANDY_ASUS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Scan</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2017/12/02 14:03:02</a></li>
      </ul>
      <select id="mobile-breadcrumbs" class="hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl">
        <option value="dr_know">Dr Know</option>
        <option value="customers">Customers</option>
        <option value="abc_electric">ABC Electric</option>
        <option value="it">IT</option>
        <option value="andy_asus">ANDY_ASUS</option>
        <option value="scan">Scan</option>
        <option value="date">2017/12/02 14:03:02</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //change dropdown to last value in breadcrumbs
     var lastone = $("#mobile-breadcrumbs option:last-child").val()
   $('#mobile-breadcrumbs option[value="' + lastone + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected')

   //get value of your dropdown option, that value should be the link to the page.
   $("#mobile-breadcrumbs").change(function() {
     var newpage = $(this).find(":selected").val()
     // code to change pages here.
   })
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/htrrbmu5/2/ Change the size of the output portion of the page to see the effect.